# Not able read Azure Key Vault's secret key through windows application

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, secret-key

We are trying to read Azure Key vault’s secret through a windows application (not any azure application/resource.
Here is what we are trying to achieve –

```
1. Created key vault 
2.  Added secret
3.  Added user (Azure AD User) to access policies and given required permissions.
4.  Running a windows application (not azure) to get those keys and getting error. (User who is running this application has already been added to access policies of key vault)
```

**Below is error**

at Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider.d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential.d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential.d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.d__65.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.d__13.MoveNext()

Comment: Probably the provider is failing to use its authentication methods. You'll need to run the app in Visual Studio (and enable the authentication in options), or you can install the AZ CLI and login to that (+ select the right subscription) before you run the app.

Comment: Could you provide the error message itself as well? You only posted the stacktrace, not the actual message.

Comment: This isn't a Key Vault problem but an authentication problem. How are you logging into your Windows application?  If you can post code, this would be easier to understand.

There's also the option of using a Service Principal (a registered application).  This would give you a specific identity that is always used to access the key vault for the secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure following 3 dlls are present in your solution. If not get these from nuget

1. Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform.dll
2. Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault
3. Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication

Comment: Thanks. It is working fine after adding above mentioned dll's. But when I remove reference of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform.dll  then it is not working with my credentials but working with other credentials. My question is what would be the difference in those two user profiles from which one is needed Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform.dll ?

Answer (score 0):

The windows application needs to have an Azure Active directory ID associated with it. 
If you read the basic concepts of Key Vault there are 2 recommended ways to access Key Vault. 1) Using Managed Identities where the application that's trying to interact/authenticate with Key Vault needs to have an identity that's managed by Azure. 
2) Use a service principal and certificate to authenticate to Key Vault.

In this case, if it's a locally running windows application it needs to authenticate to key vault using a service principal and a certificate.

Comment: Read the basic concepts here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-whatis#basic-concepts

Comment: Same piece of code is working for one user and not for another. Both users exists in Azure Active directory. Only the difference is the user for which it is working created the Key vault and added secrets in azure. The use user for which code is not working can see the secrets in azure portal but can read those secrets through code.

@Prashanth Y  - If there is any issue related to authentication using service principle or certificate , then it should fail for both users.

Comment: @Manjushri you need to grant permissions to your user b in azure key vault